# how to catch double values from formatted text file in c#

Tags: c#, text, double

I want to extract data from an `excell` file and edit some fields and save it in the DB my `excell` file contains values like this `alpha=10e-4 , BETA=10e-4` i want to save for example alpha and beta values in a separate fields and store theme in double format this is how i am doing this:
for example if the string file is `rr="alpha=10e-4 , BETA=10e-4"`

```
string AlPHA="";
string BETA="";
ALPHA=rr.substring(0,indexof(",")+1);
ALPHA=ALPHA.replace("alpha=","");
ALPHA=ALPHA.replace(" , ","");
double alpha=convet.ToDouble(ALPHA);
```

i am pretty sure that this way is not clever way of extracting values from a text file, and it may not work when we add an extra space or something like that
so how can i do this? what is the parallels?

Comment: What exactly do you have there? Do you have a text file or an excel file?

Comment: it is an exell file that some of the cells contain text.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions, first, read all file to a string variable and pass it to Regex.Matches:

```
var input = File.ReadAllText(path);
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(\d+e\-\d)");

foreach (var match in matches)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example the problem is this line

```
ALPHA=ALPHA.replace(" , ","");
```

replace it with

```
ALPHA = ALPHA.Replace(",", "").Trim();
```

and it worked (`alpha=0.001`)

Comment: the problem is not how this works and i got error i was just looking for new way of doing this